# Courtesy page when JBoss is deploying a web application

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, web-deployment, jboss-eap-6

I'm deploying a web app on JBoss EAP 6.2.0 in production environment, this application overwrites the welcome-root of JBoss with this configuration:

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-web>
      <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
      <virtual-host>customHost</virtual-host>
   </jboss-web>
```

**domain.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp"/>
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="443"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl key-alias="xxx" password="YYYY" certificate-key-file="${jboss.home.dir}/certs/custom.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
        </virtual-server>
        <virtual-server name="customHost" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="WeAreWeb">
            <alias name="realestate.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

As you can see, I've disabled the JBoss welcome root on my config, because the app is deployed on root context.

Is there any way to provide a custom 'work in progress' page to display when the application is being deployed?

Comment: Your users are connecting directly to Jboss or they connect through (for example Apache)?

Comment: Hi alphamikevictor, 
thank for your support, they are connecting directly to JBoss.

Comment: If you can change the way users connect to your application (normally installing an apache in front of Jboss) you can have 2 configurations of apache: one making a proxypass or AJP to your Jboss and a second one showing instead a "Work in progress" page. Before starting the deploy change the configuration of apache to the one showing the "Work in progress" page, once the application is again deployed switch back to the proxypass/AJP configuration.

Comment: Thanks alphamikevictor, so there is no way to obtain a sorry page with JBoss only, I must install Apache in order to obtain the desidered behavior, am I right?

Comment: as far as I know you cannot get your expected behaviour with jboss only and you need to perform some tricks to get the results.